# using xaml to define content of user control and binding data

Tags: xaml, user-controls, contentcontrol

I am trying to create a user control that has a contentcontrol which binds its content tio a dependancy object. The code is as follows

Xaml

```
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="NotifyContent" Content="{Binding ElementName=notifyBarCtrl, Path=Content, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
```

c#

```
public object Content
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(NotifyBar));
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to define the content as a textblock using xaml and then bind the text property to a string in my application it fails to update when the string changes:

My application code is as follows

Xaml

```
<ctrl:NotifyBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ctrl:NotifyBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Height="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=NotifyMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ctrl:NotifyBar.Content>
</ctrl:NotifyBar>
```

c#

```
    public string NotifyMessage
    {
        get { return _NotifyMessage; }
        set 
        {
            if (_NotifyMessage != value)
            {
                _NotifyMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NotifyMessage");
            }
        }
    }
```

any suggestions as to what I might be missing or might have done wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks

[Edit]

I have since changed the Content dependancy property to NotifyContent as I was getting a warning that it was overriding the Content to UserControl but this still hasnt resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that it was because I was using elementname within the the textblock.

If I set the DataContext of the usercontrol to the element and bind to the propertiesit works.

see below:

```
<ctrl:NotifyBar DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow}"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ctrl:NotifyBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Height="30" Text="{Binding Path=NotifyMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ctrl:NotifyBar.Content>
</ctrl:NotifyBar>
```